How to replace a matrix X columns
The code is intended to choose a subset of the columns of matrix X and label it as matrix Xnew.
        p=3;i = 1;

        While[i < p + 1;

        score = Abs[ML[[i]]/Sqrt[M[[i, i]]]];

        If[score > 1.96, Xnew[[All, i]] = X[[All, i]] , Drop[X[[All, i]]];

        i++;

        ];


This is useful.

You code is not very idiomatic form of Wolfram Language and it contains errors.  Can you give examples of the intended inputs and outputs? Also do not confuse Set (=) with Equal (==).

Hello, and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I modified the code.  I already have a p by p matrix M, matrix X, and MLE values.  I am trying to update matrix X using the condition in the if statement. This code is a part of a much larger code.

Xnew = Array[Subscript[xnew, ##] &, {n, p}];
i = 1;
While[i < p + 1;
score = Abs[MLE[[i]]/Sqrt[M[[i, i]]]];
If[score > 1.96, Xnew[[All, i]] = X[[All, i]]], Drop[X[[All, i]]];
i++;];

Based on your comments and answer, I think I see what you're trying to do and will walk through this step by step.
You have a matrix X which I'll reproduce here so we don't lose track of it:
X = {{1, 2.41784, 3.24975}, {1, 2.52409, 3.05216}, {1, 2.8274, 3.1462}, 
     {1, 2.39089, 3.25225}, {1, 2.12837, 3.41139}, {1, 2.45565, 3.1021}, 
     {1, 2.14414, 3.71765}, {1, 2.08407, 3.47637}, {1, 2.88103, 3.57581}, 
     {1, 2.2213, 3.72108}, {1, 2.38428, 3.91413}, {1, 2.39067, 3.98295}, 
     {1, 2.02609, 3.9943}, {1, 2.94577, 3.97042}, {1, 2.94463, 3.15946}, 
     {1, 2.85084, 3.2971}, {1, 2.62584, 3.88721}, {1, 2.25133, 3.67963}, 
     {1, 2.0556, 3.66948}, {1, 2.38852, 3.81458}, {1, 2.29013, 3.45672}, 
     {1, 2.01679, 3.6825}, {1, 2.20743, 3.70114}, {1, 2.39418, 3.97274}, 
     {1, 2.52771, 3.38461}, {1, 2.57211, 3.08659}, {1, 2.75212, 3.10829}, 
     {1, 2.16406, 3.03319}, {1, 2.3537, 3.03954}, {1, 2.67163, 3.13452}};

This matrix is 30 by 3 (30 "rows" and 3 "columns"). You would like to select some columns from this matrix according to a score function applied to some other data. That other data looks like this, again replicated here for clarity/concreteness.
MLE = {1.28875, -1.64043, 0.539978};
M = {{2.13317, -0.224355, -0.455894}, 
     {-0.224355, 0.0268774, 0.0459275}, 
     {-0.455894, 0.0459275, 0.0987292}};

Your score expression looks like this
Abs[MLE[[i]]/Sqrt[M[[i, i]]]]

and what you're wanting is to capture all columns of index i from X such that the above score for i is greater than 1.96. You tried to do this with a loop, and I thought about demonstrating it that way to reduce confusion, but honestly it's more confusing that way, and so here is an alternate method...
So, let's first just get our scores.
p = 3; (* I don't know if this should be hard-coded, if not you could do the following *)
p = Length[MLE];

scores = Table[Abs[MLE[[i]]/Sqrt[M[[i, i]]]], {i, 1, p}]
(* {0.882381, 10.0061, 1.71851} *)
(* see comments below for alternate *)

Now, at what positions does the score exceed 1.96?
columns = Select[Range[p], scores[[#]] > 1.96 &]
(* {2} *)
(* see comments below for alternate *)

And finally, capture the columns as a new matrix:
Xnew = X[[All, columns]]
(* {{2.41784}, {2.52409}, {2.8274}, 
    {2.39089}, {2.12837}, {2.45565}, 
    {2.14414}, {2.08407}, {2.88103}, 
    {2.2213}, {2.38428}, {2.39067}, 
    {2.02609}, {2.94577}, {2.94463}, 
    {2.85084}, {2.62584}, {2.25133}, 
    {2.0556}, {2.38852}, {2.29013}, 
    {2.01679}, {2.20743}, {2.39418}, 
    {2.52771}, {2.57211}, {2.75212}, 
    {2.16406}, {2.3537}, {2.67163}} *)

At this point, I'm not sure if we're done. You seem to be doing something directly to X, but it seems like Xnew and X will match at the end anyway, so I'm assuming that just having Xnew is sufficient.
Alternates
You can avoid a lot of the index manipulation in the above solution. For example, you don't need p or a Table to calculate the scores. Instead, you can just do arithmetic on the lists:
scores = Abs[MLE/Sqrt[Diagonal[M]]]

And for the columns, you also don't need to depend on p. You can use something like Position or SelectPositions (the latter being from the function repository):
columns = Flatten[Position[scores, _?(GreaterThan[1.96])]]

or
columns = Flatten[ResourceFunction["SelectPositions"][scores, GreaterThan[1.96]]]

or
 columns = ResourceFunction["SelectIndices"][scores, GreaterThan[1.96]]


The code is working and I can add it now to my main code. Many thanks. I appreciate your time.

For illustration, here's a sample X:
X = ArrayReshape[Alphabet[], {5, 5}]
(* {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, 
    {"f", "g", "h", "i", "j"}, 
    {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}, 
    {"p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, 
    {"u", "v", "w", "x", "y"}} *)

Choosing a subset of the columns if we know which columns we want. Let's say we know we want 1, 3, and 4. Then Part can do the job easily.
X[[All, {1, 3, 4}]]
(* {{"a", "c", "d"}, 
   {"f", "h", "i"}, 
   {"k", "m", "n"}, 
   {"p", "r", "s"}, 
   {"u", "w", "x"}} *)

So, the only remaining issue is how to choose the columns. You haven't provided us with your exact criteria, but it seems like you have a way to write a function that can give a score for each i in a range. So, just apply that score to a Range:
columns = Select[Range[5], GreaterThan[1.96]@*score]

I assume the range will match the width of the matrix, so I chose Range[5] to match my sample data. I assume you can formulate a score function, and this code won't evaluate completely until you provide a definition for score. Now we can combine these two parts:
Xnew = X[[All, columns]]


Thanks, the updated code still does not work.  I added more info to the code.

I have modified the original code and included more info.  However, I still can not get the updated matrix.  Thanks.
p = 3;
Xnew = Array[Subscript[xnew, ##] &, {n, p}];

Array[score, p];


X = {{1, 2.41784, 3.24975}, {1, 2.52409, 3.05216}, {1, 2.8274, 
3.1462}, {1, 2.39089, 3.25225}, {1, 2.12837, 3.41139}, {1, 
2.45565, 3.1021}, {1, 2.14414, 3.71765}, {1, 2.08407, 
3.47637}, {1, 2.88103, 3.57581}, {1, 2.2213, 3.72108}, {1, 
2.38428, 3.91413}, {1, 2.39067, 3.98295}, {1, 2.02609, 
3.9943}, {1, 2.94577, 3.97042}, {1, 2.94463, 3.15946}, {1, 
2.85084, 3.2971}, {1, 2.62584, 3.88721}, {1, 2.25133, 
3.67963}, {1, 2.0556, 3.66948}, {1, 2.38852, 3.81458}, {1, 
2.29013, 3.45672}, {1, 2.01679, 3.6825}, {1, 2.20743, 
3.70114}, {1, 2.39418, 3.97274}, {1, 2.52771, 3.38461}, {1, 
2.57211, 3.08659}, {1, 2.75212, 3.10829}, {1, 2.16406, 
3.03319}, {1, 2.3537, 3.03954}, {1, 2.67163, 3.13452}};


MLE = {1.28875, -1.64043, 0.539978};

M = {{2.13317, -0.224355, -0.455894}, {-0.224355, 0.0268774, 
0.0459275}, {-0.455894, 0.0459275, 0.0987292}};


i = 1;

While[i < p + 1;

score[i] = Abs[MLE[[i]]/Sqrt[M[[i, i]]]];

columns = Select[Range[p], GreaterThan[1.96]@*score];

i++;
];

Xnew = X[[All, columns]]


You should really update your question rather than add an "answer" that doesn't answer your question.
